# How to deploy WCF Service Application (Framework 4.0) using Windows XP IIS 5.1?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-5

How to deploy WCF Service Application made with Visual Studio 2010 (Framework 4.0) with Windows XP IIS 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new virtual directory in IIS to host your WCF service application - you can either put the application in inetpub\wwwroot, or have the virtual directory point to the physical location of the application.

In the properties for the virtual directory, ensure that the ASP.NET tab has ASP.NET version set to 4.0.30319.

Also make sure your Web.config file has the proper settings for the environment your deploying to (i.e., service address and anything else that might be specific to the environment).

You won't have WAS in 5.1, so you won't be able to use NetTcpBinding.

You can also look on MSDN for more information - [How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx), though it's written for later versions of IIS.